# How to Convert SASS on the fly to CSS in Python?

Tags: python, css, sass, bottle

I come from a PHP-background, more specific Symfony2. Symfony2 has a feature via Assetic to [autmagically convert SASS file into CSS](http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Sass-Compass-Assetic-In-Ten-Minutes).

Now I am working on my first python project using the bottle framework, and I am wondering if there exists a likewise way to have an on-the-fly CSS-generation of SASS files.

Is there an equivalent to Assetic filters in the python world?

Manually running `compass` in the background is not an option. I want to use `SASS`, but the whole ordeal should be *very* coy on my workflow.

Comment: Is something wrong with the watch command?

Comment: @cimmanon Nothing is wrong with it per se. I just do not want to be bothered to always think of running it when editing the sass files. And I also do not want to think of compiling the SASS files when deploying. I want my workflow to remain the same as if I was editing CSS files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991603/sass-to-css-converting-utility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thinking about this differently, I thought I could just have my python script run `sass --watch source.sass:target.css` and so I followed up [how to run bash commands in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python). Hence my `__init_.py` now includes:

```
bashCommand = "sass --watch ./css/main.sass:./css/main.css"
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This leads to the `sass` file being automagically converted to `css` without me having to worry about the whole `sass` conversion aspect.

Comment: That's pretty neat idea, typically they say not to use ``__init__.py`` for code, but if there's an exception, I could see this being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [Boussole](https://boussole.readthedocs.io/en/latest). It uses [libsass-python](https://github.com/sass/libsass-python) and [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) to watch and automatically compile any given file or directory! Just use the command `boussole watch` and specify the source and target file/directory.